# Para que serve a pseudo-classe :lang?

Tags: css

Já revirei a internet de ponta cabeça e acho sempre a mesma coisa como no site w3schools dizendo que é para definir regras especias para idiomas. eu sei que tem como colocar caracteres entorno do elemento por exemplo

```
q:lang(p1)
{
    quotes: "+" "+";
}
```

Mais afinal qual é sua funcionalidade? o atributo por exemplo lang="pt-br" define a linguagem do documento mais se caso eu for usar a pseudo-elemento :lang no html seria como por exemplo

```
html:lang(p1)
{
    quotes: "pt" "br";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Vamos deixar algumas coisas claras para facilitar o entendimento. Basicamente o `:lang()` é apenas um seletor. Ele não serve para nada além de indicar o elemento ao qual o CSS deve ser aplicado.

Por exemplo:

```
p:lang(it) {
    color:red;
}
```

Isso que dizer apenas que o elemento `<p>` que tiver o atributo `lang="it"` deve ter a cor vermelha

```css
p:lang(it) {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<p lang="it">Cosa nostra!</p>
```

---

Agora o atributo HTML `lang=""` vai muito além de ser apenas usado como um seletor no CSS, ele determina a linguagem com está contida no elemento, e ela pode ser muito útil em questões de acessibilidade, semântica, e até como referência para indexação em mecanismos de busca e para tradutores automáticos e leitores de tela.

O indicado é que se determine a linguagem do conteúdo do documento na tag `html`, tipo: `<html lang="en">`. Isso vai indicar para mecanismos de busca, ou leitores de telas ou tradutores que a linguagem do documento é em inglês, porem se dentro desse documento vc tiver uma citação em italiano vc pode colocar um `<p lang="it">Cosa nostra!</p>` isso vai deixar o elemento mais semântico e acessível para *screen readrs* e tradutores.

Artigo interessante da **W3C** sobre `lang`

**How should I set the language of the content in my HTML page?**
*"Como devo definir o idioma do conteúdo na minha página HTML?"*

> Always use a language attribute on the html tag to declare the default language of the text in the page. When the page contains content in another language, add a language attribute to an element surrounding that content.

PORTUGUÊS: *"Sempre use um atributo de idioma na tag html para declarar o idioma padrão do texto na página. **Quando a página contiver conteúdo em outro idioma, adicione um atributo de idioma a um elemento em torno desse conteúdo.**"*

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations

Comment: atá valeu de novo cara, se é foda 

Comment: @LeandroNascimento  nem tanto jovem rss! A pergunta foi interessante, os exemplos que eles usam por ai para `lang` é que deixam as coisas confusas, mas basicamente é um atributo HTML como outro qq, que vc pode usar no CSS para definir onde vai aplicar o estilo. Nada de mais... []´s